# Content Security Policy: hash for font-src: data

Tags: content-security-policy

I'd like to specify a hash to my CSP of an allowed font.

Currently my default-src is none, then for font-src I have 'self'.

My font is currently included as data, like so: "data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAARAQ..."

Instead of just adding data: to my font-src, I'd like add the hash. I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to properly do it. I've taken the sha256 hash of "data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAARAQ..." and included it as 'sha256-asldfkj' in my font-src, but that did not work.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @granty thanks for the link, that answeres my question. I was expecting that answer, but just felt like this documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/font-src) was still somehow indicating that a hash is a valid source for font-src.

Your link clears that up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). `'hash-value'` kind of `'sha256-he03geRc75f'`, `'sha384-nd78ro9=='` etc. are applied to the inline scripts and inline styles only, see the second ["Note" to para 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-element-to-source-list) of CSP3 spec.

2). CSP3 spec [did extend](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash) hashes usage to external scripts (but Firefox still have a [bug](http://csplite.com/csp/test161/#bug_Firefox_hash-value) with this). Note in this case you have to use `integrity=` attribute in the tag.

Therefore hashes are not applicable to fonts because of **para 1)** above (plus, you probably forgot to use the `integrity=` attribute).
The data:-URL is considered as URL to external resource, not as inline. Therefore hashes are not applicable because of **para 2)** above too.

Note: The `'hash-value'` is [supported](https://csplite.com/csp/test364/) to allow external scripts with data:-urls in Chrome.